# Change server mapping with phpunit and xdebug

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I followed this tutorial to set up PhpStorm to use xdebug on vagrant: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

When I got to step 7, and I got to [this dialog](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/download/attachments/50497722/incoming_connection_debug3.png?version=1&modificationDate=1444122378000&api=v2), I chose my `index.php` file via manual selection, rather than using the radio dialog to import the mappings from my deployment server.

However, with that setting, I seem to only be able to set xdebug breakpoints in `index.php`, and not in any of the files / classes that index.php kicks off to do work.

I'd like to get that dialog (linked above) back, but it's not accessible through menus and invalidating the caches didn't help. Is there some way to get it to pop back up? Alternatively, is there some other way to set breakpoints in files called on by the `index.php` I already have mapped?

Comment: *" Is there some way to get it to pop back up?"* Only by deleting that "PHP | Servers` entry (or changing "host" field to some another value so it's no longer "valid" for your requests.

Comment: *"Alternatively, is there some other way..."* No clue what you have got there. But so far it looks like you have provide wrong mappings .. or did not provide mappings for some subfolders. You have to keep in mind that xdebug works with final/resolved URLs only while IDE sees symlinks as is. That;s why it's important to have correct mappings. I suggest to enable xdebug logging to see what file path gets actually executed (the path as seen by xdebug) to have some hints on such possibility.

Comment: Another things to consider: 1) always place breakpoints on simple & single-line instructions -- on some lines xdebug cannot break due to the way how PHP generates byte code 2) you can always try programmatic breakpoint: `xdebug-break();` in your code.